# UIPickerView won't allow changing font name and size via delegate's `attributedTitleForRow...`

Tags: cocoa, fonts, size, uipickerview, nsattributedstring

I use the following func to change the font color and font size, the color works but the font name and font size refuse to work.

```
func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, attributedTitleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> NSAttributedString? 

var myTitle = NSAttributedString(string: titleData, attributes: [NSFontAttributeName:UIFont(name: "Arial-BoldMT", size: 45)!, NSForegroundColorAttributeName:UIColor.whiteColor()])
```

any help?

Thx.

Comment: It's not just in Swift...

Comment: Same issue on iOS 9 beta 5

Comment: Still doesn't work in iOS 11.4 with Swift 4.1 and Xcode 9.4.1.  Maybe it's time to file a bug.

Comment: iOS 12 not work too.

Comment: iOS 15 checking in; still doesn't work.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

I have a another option may be it helpfull for you..

Do all work that need for normal picker view : for more help  [**UIPickerView make in Swift iOS**](http://www.jogendra.com/2014/11/uipickerview-make-in-swift-ios.html)

Now follow this step : - you can use method of **viewForRow** like this

```
func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, viewForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int, reusingView view: UIView!) -> UIView
{
    var pickerLabel = UILabel()
    pickerLabel.textColor = UIColor.blackColor()
    pickerLabel.text = "PickerView Cell Title"
   // pickerLabel.font = UIFont(name: pickerLabel.font.fontName, size: 15)
    pickerLabel.font = UIFont(name: "Arial-BoldMT", size: 15) // In this use your custom font
    pickerLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center
    return pickerLabel
}
```

**Updated Swift 3**

```
func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, viewForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int, reusingView view: UIView!) -> UIView
{
    let pickerLabel = UILabel()
    pickerLabel.textColor = UIColor.black
    pickerLabel.text = "PickerView Cell Title"
    // pickerLabel.font = UIFont(name: pickerLabel.font.fontName, size: 15)
    pickerLabel.font = UIFont(name: "Arial-BoldMT", size: 15) // In this use your custom font
    pickerLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.center
    return pickerLabel
}
```

**Updated Swift 5**

```
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, viewForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int, reusing view: UIView?) -> UIView
    {
        let pickerLabel = UILabel()
        pickerLabel.textColor = UIColor.white
        pickerLabel.text = "PickerView Cell Title"
        // pickerLabel.font = UIFont(name: pickerLabel.font.fontName, size: 15)
        pickerLabel.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 20) // In this use your custom font
        pickerLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.center
        return pickerLabel
    }
```

May be it help full for you, I also used this in my project.

Comment: Yes, your codes work. But I need to get the recalculated title data from  pickerView(pickerView, titleForRow: row, forComponent: component). By the way, how can I post codes in comment?

Comment: `pickerView(_:titleForRow:forComponent:)`<br/>
`pickerView(_:attributedTitleForRow:forComponent:)`<br/>
`pickerView(_:viewForRow:forComponent:reusingView:)`<br/> the three above can also show the pickerview content, but should not use them at the same time, I somehow use two of them. Now only using the last one and problem solved. <br/>Thanks all.

Answer (score 9):

You can declare the datasource for pickerview

```
let arrDataSource:[String] = ["row 1","row 2","row 3"]
```

then use this array of string as title for row in below function

```
func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, viewForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int, reusingView view: UIView!) -> UIView

{
    let pickerLabel = UILabel()
    pickerLabel.textColor = UIColor.blackColor()
    pickerLabel.text = arrDataSource[row]
     pickerLabel.font = UIFont(name: pickerLabel.font.fontName, size: 15)
    //pickerLabel.font = UIFont(name: "Arial-BoldMT", size: 15) // In this use your custom font
    pickerLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center
    return pickerLabel
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

SWIFT 3

```
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, viewForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int, reusing view: UIView?) -> UIView {

    var string = ""

    let pickerLabel = UILabel()
    pickerLabel.textColor = UIColor.white
    pickerLabel.text = string
    pickerLabel.font = UIFont(name: "Rubik-Regular", size: 22) // In this use your custom font
    pickerLabel.textAlignment = .center

    return pickerLabel

}
```

Answer (score 2):

**Swift 4.1 / Xcode 9.4.1**

Obviously you can select you own font, but here I'm using System Bold 13.

```
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, viewForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int, reusing view: UIView?) -> UIView {
    let pickerLabel = UILabel()
    pickerLabel.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 13)
    pickerLabel.textColor = UIColor.black
    pickerLabel.textAlignment = .center
    pickerLabel.text = "PickerView Cell Title"

    return pickerLabel
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To further elaborate on https://stackoverflow.com/users/4020910/bennythenerd answer with UILabel I'd go with a bit more memory optimised solution that reuses the labels:

```
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, viewForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int, reusing view: UIView?) -> UIView {
    let pickerLabel: UILabel
    if let label = view as? UILabel {
        pickerLabel = label
    } else {
        pickerLabel = UILabel()
        pickerLabel.font = UIFont(name: "Rubik-Regular", size: 22)
        pickerLabel.textAlignment = .center
    }
    pickerLabel.text = pickerData[row] //This is your string
    return pickerLabel
}
```

Comment: This is the right way to go.